# JQuery Tablesorter: Have column show as another is sorted

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I am creating a sorted table, I would like it when I click for one column to be sorted another column shows next to it. I currently have it that as you click it once it shows, the problem with this is when it is sorted the other way the column disappears when I still need to see it. When another column is clicked I would also want the other one to hide and the one clicked to show. Please let me know if i haven't explained this well!! This code is shown below from jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#CATAID").click(function(){
        $("td:nth-child(7),th:nth-child(7)").toggle();
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Can you share your HTML... and I think you mean "column" not "row" right?

Comment: Ahh yes sorry, I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient method of doing this would be with css... then large tables won't be effected by lag while hiding/showing the table cells ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3635/)):

CSS

```
th:nth-child(4), td:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
}
.toggle th:nth-child(4),
.toggle td:nth-child(4) {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter-blue">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AlphaNumeric</th>
            <th>Numeric</th>
            <th class="toggler">Animals</th>
            <th class="toggler">Sites</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('th').click(function(){
        // toggle "toggle" class name on the table when the
        // header with a class name of "toggler" is clicked
        $('table').toggleClass( 'toggle', $(this).hasClass('toggler') );
    });

    $('table').tablesorter();
});
```

The reason the last column has a "toggler" class is to allow it to be sorted.

A method to allow css animation could be added, but I think it would only work if the toggled column had the contents wrapped in a div that was animated (in width) instead of trying to animate the table cells.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I seem to have a problem when calling the 'hasclass' as classes don't seem to work with the tableheader. I think it might be because of in my CSS so I had to use id instead to format the hidden columns. Is there a way to do this with attribute id in the 'th', i tried myself but there is no '.hasId' attribute so it doesn't work.

Comment: The function is `hasClass` with a capital "C"... and I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. If you need to use an ID, try `this.id === "abc"`. For two ID comparisons, use `this.id === "abc" || this.id === "xyz"`.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant to type it like that. When I put in thee code exactly as you have I find it does not work and when I wanted to hide the column intitally I had to use an ID not as class as it just did not work. Sorry how do I put that into the javascript so I can use the ID?

Comment: Please modify the demo I shared to show the problems you are having.

Comment: Is it okay if i used your external resources on jsfiddle so I can show you whats not working please?

Comment: yes, go ahead and use those resources for demo purposes. If you need a resource for your website, use http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery.tablesorter

Comment: Okay thanks, the js fiddle i created is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhysp/4uLLptr9/ It doesn't seem to want to work with classes for some reason.

Comment: The jQuery selector is missing the `#` (`$("#myTable")`) - [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uLLptr9/10/)

Comment: Thanks that works now, but is there a way to get it working for several columns as there are quite a few columns which I would like to show/hide just by clicking the column next to it?

Comment: Maybe you would consider using the [columnSelector widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-column-selector.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this myself, I don't know if its the best way but it works for me.

Here's how I did it:

first I added these into my html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

I typed this into the script tag in html:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("put column header id here").click(function(){
        $("td:nth-child(column num want to show),th:nth-child(column num want to show)").show() 
        $("put all the other column headers id in here except the one showed seperated by comma").click(function(){   $("td:nth-child(column num want to hide),th:nth-child(column num want to hide)").hide(); 
        });
     }); 
});'
```

Then you need to do this all the columns you want this for.

You can add additional things to the show/hide by making the columns slide etc, I tried this but it made the table effect so slow so I got rid of it.

But  for the slide effect you just add the following into show/hide parentheses:

```
  "slide",{direction: "left"},1000
```

and adding to the top of your html:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
```